# Why the attribute didn't inherited after I called super(...) on the subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to get a class attribute from the subclass. The attribute is assigned to the value on the superclass initialization. See:

```
class A:
    _b = None
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        _b = b

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(B,self).__init__(a=a, b=b)
        print('Try to get _b value:', self._b)

B(4,5)
```

On initialization of class B, super(...).**init** is called so the constructor of A class should be called. This results in b of being assigned to A._b.
However, when I try to get self._b from class B, it seems like it doesn't initialize A because self._b is equal None.

Answer (score 2):

Your `A.__init__` doesn't initialize `self._b`, it initializes a local variable called `_b`.  Since this is a local variable it disappears as soon as that function returns.

Comment: …so change it to `A._b = b`

Comment: @Sam Stafford Thanks a lot. Forgot the function returns None by default, but now when you say that I remember.